# Is there a way to manage stock levels?

Tags: 8, commerce

Is there a way to manage stock levels with Drupal 8 Commerce?

I am not sure, but I believe [Configure product attributes](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/user-guide/products/configure-product-attributes) refers to product attributes, but it doesn't outline how to create stock management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct: The quantity available for a product is not considered a product attribute. A product attribute is, for example, color, size, weight. The quantity available in store is a value associated with the store, not an intrinsic property of the product.

Using only Drupal Commerce, you cannot manage stocks. There is a [Commerce Stock](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_stock) module, but it just has only a development snapshot, for Drupal 8, which has been updated on November, 2017.

> #### The stock module does two main things
>
> - Maintain stock levels
> - Implement validation of stock to prevent users from ordering out of stock items
>
> #### The module does the following stock validation checks
>
> - Disable the add to cart button for out of stock products
> - Validates the add to cart quantity widget
> - Checks current Cart quantity when adding to your cart (so if stock is 10 and you got 6 in your cart you can only add 4)
> - Checks that all products and quantities in the shopping cart (/cart) are in stock
> - On Checkout if you attempt to enter, continue or complete with out of stock items you get redirected to the shopping cart

Comment: Thank you so much for your very detailed answer.  I have marked this one as accepted.